# How to put a gradient color into an ion icon?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, gradient, ionicons

This is an idea, but it doesn't work at all...

```
<ion-icon class="color" name="calendar-outline"></ion-icon>

.color{
    --border-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(to right, #003b5c, #770bf4, #7c37fc, #50a0ff) !important;
}
```

Any idea?

I'm working with ionic6

Comment: try this
.color{
background: linear-gradient(to right, #003b5c, #770bf4, #7c37fc, #50a0ff);
    color: #fff;
}

Comment: @RaviAshara thanks for answer, this code put de background of the icon in gradient, not the icon :(

Comment: Did you find any solution yet?